# how to get text value of title attribute of div tag in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

i am trying to extract player names from [sofifa.com](https://sofifa.com/players?col=oa&sort=desc&showCol%5B0%5D=pi&showCol%5B1%5D=ae&showCol%5B2%5D=hi&showCol%5B3%5D=wi&showCol%5B4%5D=pf&showCol%5B5%5D=oa&showCol%5B6%5D=pt&showCol%5B7%5D=bo&showCol%5B8%5D=bp&showCol%5B9%5D=gu&showCol%5B10%5D=jt&showCol%5B11%5D=le&showCol%5B12%5D=vl&showCol%5B13%5D=wg&showCol%5B14%5D=rc&showCol%5B15%5D=ta&showCol%5B16%5D=cr&showCol%5B17%5D=fi&showCol%5B18%5D=he&showCol%5B19%5D=sh&showCol%5B20%5D=vo&showCol%5B21%5D=ts&showCol%5B22%5D=dr&showCol%5B23%5D=cu&showCol%5B24%5D=fr&showCol%5B25%5D=lo&showCol%5B26%5D=bl&showCol%5B27%5D=to&showCol%5B28%5D=ac&showCol%5B29%5D=sp&showCol%5B30%5D=ag&showCol%5B31%5D=re&showCol%5B32%5D=ba&showCol%5B33%5D=tp&showCol%5B34%5D=so&showCol%5B35%5D=ju&showCol%5B36%5D=st&showCol%5B37%5D=sr&showCol%5B38%5D=ln&showCol%5B39%5D=te&showCol%5B40%5D=ar&showCol%5B41%5D=in&showCol%5B42%5D=po&showCol%5B43%5D=vi&showCol%5B44%5D=pe&showCol%5B45%5D=cm&showCol%5B46%5D=td&showCol%5B47%5D=ma&showCol%5B48%5D=sa&showCol%5B49%5D=sl&showCol%5B50%5D=tg&showCol%5B51%5D=gd&showCol%5B52%5D=gh&showCol%5B53%5D=gk&showCol%5B54%5D=gp&showCol%5B55%5D=gr&showCol%5B56%5D=tt&showCol%5B57%5D=bs&showCol%5B58%5D=wk&showCol%5B59%5D=sk&showCol%5B60%5D=aw&showCol%5B61%5D=dw&showCol%5B62%5D=ir&showCol%5B63%5D=pac&showCol%5B64%5D=sho&showCol%5B65%5D=pas&showCol%5B66%5D=dri&showCol%5B67%5D=def&showCol%5B68%5D=phy&offset=0) using python scrapy but i am getting only empty list

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klW2Y.png)

```
<div class="bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis"><img title="Argentina" alt="" src="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar.png" data-src="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar.png" data-srcset="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@2x.png 2x, https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@3x.png 3x" class="flag loaded" srcset="https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@2x.png 2x, https://cdn.sofifa.com/flags/ar@3x.png 3x" data-was-processed="true"> L. Messi</div>
```

this is my code:

response.css('table.table>tbody>tr>td.col-name>div.bp3-text-overflow-ellipsis>a::attr(title)')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to extract all team players names

```
response.css(".list tr td.col-name a::attr(data-tooltip)").extract()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use different libraries like selenium for this matter. I'm sorry I couldn't think of anything with scrappy but hopefully this could also help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time
import random

link = "https://sofifa.com/players?col=oa&sort=desc&showCol%5B0%5D=pi&showCol%5B1%5D=ae&showCol%5B2%5D=hi&showCol%5B3%5D=wi&showCol%5B4%5D=pf&showCol%5B5%5D=oa&showCol%5B6%5D=pt&showCol%5B7%5D=bo&showCol%5B8%5D=bp&showCol%5B9%5D=gu&showCol%5B10%5D=jt&showCol%5B11%5D=le&showCol%5B12%5D=vl&showCol%5B13%5D=wg&showCol%5B14%5D=rc&showCol%5B15%5D=ta&showCol%5B16%5D=cr&showCol%5B17%5D=fi&showCol%5B18%5D=he&showCol%5B19%5D=sh&showCol%5B20%5D=vo&showCol%5B21%5D=ts&showCol%5B22%5D=dr&showCol%5B23%5D=cu&showCol%5B24%5D=fr&showCol%5B25%5D=lo&showCol%5B26%5D=bl&showCol%5B27%5D=to&showCol%5B28%5D=ac&showCol%5B29%5D=sp&showCol%5B30%5D=ag&showCol%5B31%5D=re&showCol%5B32%5D=ba&showCol%5B33%5D=tp&showCol%5B34%5D=so&showCol%5B35%5D=ju&showCol%5B36%5D=st&showCol%5B37%5D=sr&showCol%5B38%5D=ln&showCol%5B39%5D=te&showCol%5B40%5D=ar&showCol%5B41%5D=in&showCol%5B42%5D=po&showCol%5B43%5D=vi&showCol%5B44%5D=pe&showCol%5B45%5D=cm&showCol%5B46%5D=td&showCol%5B47%5D=ma&showCol%5B48%5D=sa&showCol%5B49%5D=sl&showCol%5B50%5D=tg&showCol%5B51%5D=gd&showCol%5B52%5D=gh&showCol%5B53%5D=gk&showCol%5B54%5D=gp&showCol%5B55%5D=gr&showCol%5B56%5D=tt&showCol%5B57%5D=bs&showCol%5B58%5D=wk&showCol%5B59%5D=sk&showCol%5B60%5D=aw&showCol%5B61%5D=dw&showCol%5B62%5D=ir&showCol%5B63%5D=pac&showCol%5B64%5D=sho&showCol%5B65%5D=pas&showCol%5B66%5D=dri&showCol%5B67%5D=def&showCol%5B68%5D=phy&offset=0"
PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER ="/Users/Povilas/Documents/GitHub/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER)
driver.get(link)
time.sleep((random.randint(30, 50))/10)
all_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]/div')
for name in all_names:
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: He has a problem with getting a selector. Scrapy also has a xpath method, so there is no difference which library to use.